# AppCompat toolbar styling working on API level

Tags: android, android-appcompat, styling

I'm using AppCompat library to implement material design on my app. So far it is working OK when running in Android 5+, but I can't get it to work on Android 4. My project has `minSdkVersion` set to 15.

My `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
</style>
```

And toolbar XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

This works OK when run on API level 24:

[image: api level 24]

But it doesn't on API level 16:

[image: Api level 16]

I have tried changing `android:theme` to `app:theme` but this fixes nothing on old API levels, and breaks the newer API levels (the titles also become unstyled).

Comment: Did you read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes. If I try `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` (or my own style), the styling is lost even on apilevel 24

Comment: I think that means that something else is wrong then. The reason it works with `android:theme` on API 24 is probably because you are using the native theme rather than the one from appcompat.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice seems unlikely. If I remove the `android:theme` attribute, I get the same behavior as in API level 16